# Jenkins concat string and for loop index to have env variable name

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkins pipeline I use steps in which I have a for loop.  My env variable are env.server1, env.server2. I like to pass the environment variable based on index & pass it's parameter to execute another Jenkins job.

```
params.CLUSTER --> is a number 
            I have env.SERVER1 = x.x.x.x and env.SERVER2 = y.y.y.y, which i like to pass to build job as parameter.
            env.SERVER<for-loop-index>

            stage ('Running on EC2') {
            for (int i = 1; i <= "${params.CLUSTER}".toInteger(); i++) {
            branches["RebootNodes-Branch_${i}"] = { 
            build job: 'RebootNodes', parameters: [
            [$class: 'ExtendedChoiceParameterValue', name: 'server', value: env.SERVER${i}]
            ]                                   
            }
            }
            parallel branches
            }
```

Comment: Could you please provide [mcve]? What is the specific error you are getting while trying to implement what you have described?

Answer (score 0):

You can access your environment variables like shown in the example below:

```
node {
  withEnv(['VAR1=VAR1VALUE','VAR2=VAR2VALUE']) {
      for(int i=1; i<=2; i++)
      {
        println env["VAR$i"]
      }
  }
}
```